# render individual option from radio Element in Zend Forms

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this element inside my Zend form

```
$genderOptions = array( 'male'=>'male', 'Female'=>'Female');
$gender= new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('gender');
$gender->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'))
       ->setAttrib('name', 'gender')
       ->setAttrib('class', 'required error pull-right')
       ->setAttrib('id', 'gender')
       ->setRequired(false)
       ->setMultiOptions($genderOptions);
```

And I want to retrieve the inputs individually in the viewscript (phtml file). I've tried
 as

```
 <div>
 <span>Male</span>
    echo $this->myForm->gender['male'];
 </div>


<div>
<span>Female</span>
 echo   $this->myForm->gender['female'];
</div>
```

how can I do that using Zend Form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For form elements extending [`Zend_Form_Element_Multi`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Element/Multi.php) you can use the `getMultiOption($option)` to fetch a single option.

**View.phtml**

```
<div>
  <span>Male</span>
  <?php echo $this->myForm->gender->getMultiOption('male'); ?>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Female</span>
  <?php echo $this->myForm->gender->getMultiOption('female'); ?>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you may want to check that the option is available before you attempt to use it (or you will get `NULL`)

```
<?php
  $gender = $this->myForm->gender;
  $option = $gender->getMultiOptions(); // returns assoc array

  if (isset($option['male'])) 
    printf('<div><span>Male</span>%s</div>', $option['male']);
  if (isset($option['female'])) 
    printf('<div><span>Female</span>%s</div>', $option['female']);
?>
```

**Edit**

Having re-read your question I can see you're looking for the individual radio elements, rather than the value.

This may be harder to achieve as the `Zend_Form_Element_Radio` class actually represents **all** the radio options; Where the view helper [`Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/FormRadio.php) loops over each 'option' (i.e. male, female) and returns the complete HTML string with each `<input type="radio"/>` already included.

Shockingly the `Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio` helper actually has all of its HTML generation code within one method; This makes it very hard to override it without duplication.

Personally, I would :

- Create a new helper `MyNamespace_View_Helper_CustomFormRadio` extending `Zend_View_Helper_FormElement`
- Copy the entire contents of the `Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio` (`FormRadio()`) into your new helper
- Modify section where the each radio `input` is created.

For example

```
 $radio = '<div><span'
  . $this->_htmlAttribs($label_attribs) . '>'
  . (('prepend' == $labelPlacement) ? $opt_label : '')
  . '<input type="' . $this->_inputType . '"'
  . ' name="' . $name . '"'
  . ' id="' . $optId . '"'
  . ' value="' . $this->view->escape($opt_value) . '"'
  . $checked
  . $disabled
  . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
  . $this->getClosingBracket()
  . (('append' == $labelPlacement) ? $opt_label : '')
  . '</span></div>';
```

- Then you can use it within your view with `$this->customFormRadio()`

Comment: Thanks, Its extends from Zend_Form,   and when i tried your answer it print only the value

Comment: @jetawe Sorry, I miss read your question. I've updated my answer.